# For IMAP.AccessAsUser.All Scope ADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-authentication, azure-oauth

In my java web application I want to get access to user's mailbox by using jakarta mail. For that purpose I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth for OAuth2 authorization code flow.

On Azure port I setup my app and added API permissions as below

[image]

Now user is redirecting to below authorize endpoint:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/5426ee07-9b73-4a9e-8075-395ab439c6fa/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=b6067ad9-7195-430b-a35d-97b7aa7beb8f&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/callback/microsoft&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FIMAP.AccessAsUser.All%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FSMTP.Send

After entering credentials and accepting the consent redirect_uri gets hit with auth code. Based on that auth code I formed token endpoint URL and hitting it from server, the token endpoint is as follow:

URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/5426ee07-9b73-4a9e-8075-395ab439c6fa/oauth2/v2.0/token

Form Data:

```
client_id=b6067ad9-7195-430b-a35d-97b7aa7beb8f
scope=offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2FIMAP.AccessAsUser.All
redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/callback/microsoft
grant_type=authorization_code
client_secret=QUs8Q~aboLBiopTezMTKwzQjIwWsFFXjc2kCRaRs (I know I have shared the secret)
code={code received from authorize end point}
```

Response to this post request comes as:

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'b6067ad9-7195-430b-a35d-97b7aa7beb8f' named 'Email Connector'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID: dc008ced-e23f-4919-bd45-b7ae7c68b000\r\nCorrelation ID: 9b6ede03-3c05-4a78-8975-036a3cb20773\r\nTimestamp: 2022-06-07 19:51:30Z","error_codes":[65001],"timestamp":"2022-06-07 19:51:30Z","trace_id":"dc008ced-e23f-4919-bd45-b7ae7c68b000","correlation_id":"9b6ede03-3c05-4a78-8975-036a3cb20773","suberror":"consent_required"}

Here, I don't understand why the error is saying The user or administrator has not consented to use the application, user has accepted the consent after entering credentials on authorize end point. Event more If we look at the screenshot above admin has already given grant to access the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same scenario in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

**To resolve the error**, please check the **`authorize endpoint`** you are using to get the code.

- Avoid using *Microsoft graph API scopes* while getting the code.
- Replace it with the **scope** you are using to get access token like below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/Your_TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=Your_ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/callback/microsoft
&response_mode=query
&scope= offline_access https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All 
&state=12345
```

Get the **`code`** from the above authorization endpoint.

***I got the access token successfully after modifying the endpoint like below:***

[image]

***To validate the access token decode it in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) and check the **`aud`** and **`scp`** claims like below:***

[image]